# invalidating and creating NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, intervals

Everytime I am finished with my NSTimer, I want to invalidate it and create a new interval but it keeps the old interval as well as new interval. I want to invalidate NSTimes once I click the offButton. The timer stops printing "Working" but when I call my method with a different interval, it prints "Working" for both intervals.

My code is something like this:

```
-(void) fireTimer{
    NSString *textValue = [sliderLabel text];
    float value = [textValue floatValue];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:value target:self selector:@selector(vibrate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void) vibrate:(NSTimer*)timer {
    if(_offButton.selected){
        [timer invalidate];
        timer=nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"Working");


}
```

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. Just added {[_timer2 invalidate];
        _timer2=nil;} in offButton action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You aren't following the MVC design pattern by getting your values directly from the `UITextField`.  Those values should be stored in a model object, with the MVC pattern being used to get any new values from the text field into the model.  Your current implementation is very delicate and will break in the slightest breeze.  It also requires this code to have access to the UI elements, which is very inflexible; it will be better to give it access to just the model object.
2. Store the `NSTimer *` as an instance variable, and note that if you are using ARC then the `NSTimer` **retains the target** (!!) so make this instance variable `__weak` to break the retain-cycle.
3. If you want your timer to repeat then there is no need to reset it at all; this only needs to be done if the user changes the time (see point 1!).
4. Move the `if (button_selected) do_vibrate;` code into the *timer fired* method.

Answer (score 1):

The invalidation code that you use itself is correct. But it would be easier for you to keep a reference to your timer as an ivar or property.

In that case you would definetly avoid making multiple instances of a timer.